# Issue with DSCP marking using setTrafficClass and WireShark

Tags: java, network-programming, wireshark

I am trying to mark DSCP values using setTrafficClass. I have server and client set up on two different machines and I am able to print value of DSCP but I can not see it in WireShark.
I have gone through some posts online but nothing helped. I am using Windows 7 professional. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

I am more testing to see how this can be done.
Here is the client code:

try {

```
        Socket socket = new Socket(addr, 2345);
        socket.setTrafficClass(10);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        out.println("Current DSCP value: " + socket.getTrafficClass());
        out.close();
        socket.close();

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Server:

```
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String fromClient = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(fromClient);

        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In console on server side:
Current DSCP value: 10

My server code and client are on separate machines.

In wireshark I see:

Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))

I expect to see changes in wireshark and I only see default value zero.

Comment: hi ron_g_1 ~~~has result?????   i  same question~~~~~

Answer (score 1):

Last time I worked with DSCP values in Java one had to set the `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` system property to `true` due to a bug in the JVM. Othwerwise DSCP values would not be set on the underlying socket despite appearing to work in the java.net.Socket API.

Also you may have to call `setTrafficClass` before connecting the socket, it may not work after connection on some platforms.

`java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true ...`

Comment: @ron_g_1 Please update the question with the arguments you are using for `setTrafficClass(int)` and the output you are expecting.